# I have two tables I need a query that combines these two tables and sorts them by Key A, Key B, Key C, Date, Time

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables in **SQL DB**.  They both contain 3 columns that match, and additional columns that have different info in each one.  I want to write a query that Interleaves them according to date / timestamp.  Table A is for a machine that runs and takes a sample every 10 minutes.  Table B is the logfile that has entries logged when operator makes adjustments, turns machine on / off, etc.

I have used the following query but it is giving me duplicates on table A.
I did the `where(BatchTable.Batch = 'HB20419' and EventLogTable.Batch = 'HB20419')` just to cut down on the amount of date being returned until I get the query figured out.  One complication is each table has it's own date / time columns and they are named different and completely independent of each other.

```
SELECT BatchTable.Asset_Number,BatchTable.Recipe,BatchTable.Batch,BatchTable.Group_No, BatchTable.Sample_No, BatchTable.SampleDate, BatchTable.SampleTime, BatchTable.Weight, EventLogTable.EvtTime, EventLogTable.EvtValueBefore, EventLogTable.EvtValueAfter, EventLogTable.EvtComment
FROM BatchTable,EventLogTable
where(BatchTable.Batch = 'HB20419' and EventLogTable.Batch = 'HB20419')
order by Asset_Number, Recipe, Batch, Group_No, Sample_No ASC
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Never use a comma separated list of tables. That is how we joined tables in the dark ages. You need to learn how to use an ANSI-92 style join, they have been know for more than 25 years. https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins I would also suggest learning about aliases so your code is a LOT less typing (and easier to read) However, it is not clear what your question is here.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how that query would look using aliases, formatting and ANSI-92 style joins.

```
SELECT bt.Asset_Number
    , bt.Recipe
    , bt.Batch
    , bt.Group_No
    , bt.Sample_No
    , bt.SampleDate
    , bt.SampleTime
    , bt.Weight
    , elt.EvtTime
    , elt.EvtValueBefore
    , elt.EvtValueAfter
    , elt.EvtComment
FROM BatchTable bt
join EventLogTable elt on elt.Batch = bt.Batch
WHERE bt.Batch = 'HB20419'
ORDER BY Asset_Number
    , Recipe
    , Batch
    , Group_No
    , Sample_No ASC
```

Comment: Thanks Sean, I know, I have alot to learn about SQL.   Any idea how I interleave results from these two tables by timestamp.   The EventLogTable has EvtDate and EvtTime, the BatchTable has SampleDate and SampleTime.  If I had a query that would just get everything in both tables and sort it ASC by Date / Time that would be a good start.  Thanks

Comment: No idea what you mean by " interleave results from these two tables by timestamp". Sample data and desired output would go a long way to making this question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make up some sample data, but it sounds like you want to union the two tables together to "interleave" them. You can do this by aliasing the column names to match and selecting null values for the final values from the opposite table. I acknowledge that I'm guessing at your desired outcome to some extent.

Make some sample data:

```
DECLARE @batch table (SampleDate VARCHAR(MAX), SampleTime VARCHAR(MAX), Recipe 
VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE @event table (EvtTime DATETIME, EvtComment VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO @batch (SampleDate, SampleTime, Recipe) VALUES ('2018-08-09', '11:56:25 
AM', 'Peanut Butter'), ('2018-08-09', '12:11:25 PM', 'Chocolate')
INSERT INTO @event (EvtTime, EvtComment) VALUES ('2018-08-09 11:58:22 AM', 'Turned up 
speed'), ('2018-08-09 11:59:22 AM', 'Turned down temperature')
```

Then select and union to interleave:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(SampleDate + ' ' + SampleTime AS datetime)) AS [Date], 
Recipe, NULL as EvtComment FROM @batch
UNION
SELECT EvtTime AS [Date], NULL AS Recipe, EvtComment FROM @event
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Which yields:

```
Date                    Recipe                    EvtComment
----------------------- ------------------------- -------------------------
2018-08-09 11:56:25.000 Peanut Butter             NULL
2018-08-09 11:58:22.000 NULL                      Turned up speed
2018-08-09 11:59:22.000 NULL                      Turned down temperature
2018-08-09 12:11:25.000 Chocolate                 NULL
```

Comment: Here are the fields from both tables.  I just need to get all data from both tables in the order it was created (Date / Time)  

BatchTable Fields  
Asset_Number  
Recipe  
Batch  
Group_No  
Sample_No  
SampleDate  
SampleTime  
Weight  
WeightFault  
Thick  
ThickFault  
Hard  
HardFault  
Force  
S_ID  
WStatus  
AttributeType  
Side

Comment: EvtLogTable Fields  
Asset_Number   
Recipe   
Batch   
Group_No   
Sample_No   
SampleDate   
SampleTime   
Weight   
EvtTime 
EvtValueBefore   
EvtValueAfter   
EvtComment

Comment: Sorry - I am trying to format my answers but it is not working for some reason  I can't even get a simple CRLF to work.

Comment: I got it.  The key I was missing  was padding the output with nulls where needed and getting the dates in the same field.   Thanks to both you and @Sean Lange for the help.